# Запрос по столбцам, как сделать?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть 51 столбец, как можно оптимизировать этот код,чтобы не вбивать все столбцы?
-- Получение 50 то что до |
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('50|100', '|', 1);

-- Получение 100 то что после |
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('50|100', '|', -1)

для поиска в запросе можете тоже использовать что-то вроде
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX('50|100', '|', 1) = 50
В место '50|100' подставляете колонку (примерный код)

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Item0, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(Item1, '|', -1) FROM table t 
    WHERE ID = ИД пользователя

Comment: совершенно непонятно, что за схема-то. попробуйте описать через [это](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Просто как-то можно задать что-то,,чтобы не перечислять все столбцы?

Comment: это невозможно. перечислять надо. все что можно автоматизировать, это получить список столбцов в таблице программно, через show columns и сгенерировав на основе этой информации запрос с перечислением столбцов. С другой стороны, если ориентироваться на структуру которая тут вчера пробегала в вопросах сгенерировать нужный список можно просто циклом от 1 до 51

Comment: И с третьей стороны, раз эта таблица уже существует и видимо существует много кода который с ней работает, то вероятно в нем уже должны решаться эти проблемы потому как никак иначе, кроме как перечислением всех полей с такой таблицей ничего делать нельзя

Comment: Можно какие-то примеры цикла?

Comment: Как это примерно сделать?

Comment: @era-hosting, `Можно какие-то примеры цикла?` - а можно какие-нибудь примеры того, что Вы делаете с таблицей и что в ней всё-таки находится?

Comment: 51 таблица в ней находится инвентарь игровой, нахожу вещи по айди (ид|количество) и мне нужно вытащить количество, зная айди)